# Header layout bug in NextJS

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Im trying to make a header in NextJS but this keeps happenning:

[image]

I tried to use 100% width, 100% height.

My code:

```
import type { NextPage } from 'next';
import { Fragment } from 'react';
import Header from '../../components/Header';

const Home: NextPage = () => {
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <Header />
      <div>Home</div>
    </Fragment>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

The header component(its a div with background color black):

```
import { Container } from './styled';

const Header = () => {
  return <Container>HEADER</Container>;
};

export default Header;
```

[image]

Comment: First use the dev. tools to identify where this padding is coming from (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Page_Inspector/How_to/Examine_and_edit_the_box_model)

Comment: I did, i will update

Answer (score 0):

From your code looks like there are 2 possible ways that this can go wrong.

**Scenario #01**:
Check if there's some global style rules with matching styles i.e `background:black` in your globals.css (located in `styles` folder)

**Scenario #02**
You have the following container being imported in your component.
`import { Container } from './styled';`
Try commenting this out and then wrap the content in a fragment i.e
`<Fragment> HEADER </Fragment>`
If this solves the issue of black-background then it means there's something wrong about the `container` component imported.

Comment: I think the issue is with the white space around the page, not the black background.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the screenshot of the devtools it looks like there's a 8px margin on the background for some reason.

Look in your CSS files if you have any rules that do that.

If this isn't from you, override it by adding a rule in your css like

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
```